# Pass from Python a (Json)-String to PHP to create a .json-File

Tags: php, python, json, string

I write a Quiz-Generator in Python (2.7.) to generate a JSON-String.
At the end, it cleared the Clipboard and appended the Json-String to the Clipboard.
It then opens "myjson.com", and pasted the content of the Clipboard to the Form and saved it.

All that worked like i wanted to...

But the Problem was, i had no good Idea how to save the URL from the "myjson-site", to somewhere i can make a fetch()-Query to get all the Entries.
I tried to paste the generated URL from "myjson.com" to "http://listmoz.com/" ((that also worked))
but i'm not able to get the Entries cause of the "CORS"-thing...
not able to get the Entries via fetch()...

So my new Plan was to make a PHP-File on my Server, to pass my Python-String to it. Then the PHP-"Site" should take the String, and write a .json-File on the Server (then i'm able to get all the entries of the /json-Directory)
I have no Clue of PHP, but i want that it works :)

My Python-Programm produces a String like:

```
[
  {
    "num": "0",
    "tpp": "Die Antwort auf alle Fragen ist und bleibt... !",
    "pic": "https://junialeigh.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/8pysozionbxlkxqwy8qg6cgd_500.jpg",
    "val": "",
    "sol": "",
    "ans": [],
    "lnk": "",
    "question": "Was ist die Antwort auf alle Fragen..?",
    "answers": [
      "Blue",
      "42",
      "Red",
      "Purple",
      "7",
      "PI"
    ],
    "correct": 1
  },
  {
    "num": "1",
    "tpp": "",
    "pic": "https://de.hdyo.org/assets/ask-question-2-fb180173e13f21ad6ae73ba29b08cd02.jpg",
    "val": "",
    "sol": "",
    "ans": [],
    "lnk": "",
    "question": "Warum",
    "answers": [
      "Blue",
      "Weiss nicht",
      "Red",
      "Darum",
      "Purple"
    ],
    "correct": 3
  }
]
```

It should now send this String to a PHP-File that can write a "name".json-File to my Server in my /json-Directory.
Why i'm not able to do this. (perhabs cause i have absolut no idea of PHP)
**finally my Question....**
how i pass this string to a PHP-File, to produce my wanted "name".json-File...
that could not be that hard... but i read that much... i only see brackets everywhere....
Any Advice
PS: i also write the .json-File to the local-Computer, would it be easier to upload the "name".json file instead of trying to pass the String to a PHP-File....
 i need a break ._.

**Updated Question**
The Python-Tkinter-Window looks like this
[Quiz-Generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xJuX.jpg)

on the bottom you see the Label= "QuizName" and an Entry-Form.
If you finish your Quiz, python get the name of the "QuizName"-Form, and saves the .json-File on your HardDrive in the Directory of the script + /json
Example:

```
C:\py_test\json\"QuizName"+ .json
```

that works without problems... 
Now i should send that file to my "upload.php" on my website, to save it on my Server.
I found a simple "upload.php"-File with the content:

```
`
<?php
$folder = "json/";
$path = $folder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
echo "Die Datei ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " wurde hochgeladen";
} else{
    echo "Fehler!";
}
?>`
```

That works also without problems...
But it's not as UserFriendly as i want... the Python-Script should upload the *.json-File by itself... without selecting what i want to upload...
The Python-Programm knows how the File is called...
So how can i skip the "Choose your File" -PHP with the right Data...
So that it will uploaded as soon i finish my Quiz in Python...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can write the list to any file in python

```
import os
import json

json_list = [
{
    "num": "0",
    "tpp": "Die Antwort auf alle Fragen ist und bleibt... !",
    "pic": "https://junialeigh.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/8pysozionbxlkxqwy8qg6cgd_500.jpg",
    "val": "",
    "sol": "",
    "ans": [],
    "lnk": "",
    "question": "Was ist die Antwort auf alle Fragen..?",
    "answers": [
      "Blue",
      "42",
      "Red",
      "Purple",
      "7",
      "PI"
    ],
    "correct": 1
  },{
    "num": "1",
    "tpp": "",
    "pic": "https://de.hdyo.org/assets/ask-question-2-fb180173e13f21ad6ae73ba29b08cd02.jpg",
    "val": "",
    "sol": "",
    "ans": [],
    "lnk": "",
    "question": "Warum",
    "answers": [
      "Blue",
      "Weiss nicht",
      "Red",
      "Darum",
      "Purple"
    ],
    "correct": 3
  }
  ]

# for obj in json_list:
#   print(obj)


file = open( os.getcwd() + '/../../files/fruits.json', 'a')

file.write(json.dumps(json_list,indent=4))

file.close();
```

Make sure the path to your file is correct.

Once you have written (appended in this case) to your file you can read the file in php

```
<?php

$myfile = dirname(__FILE__) . "/files/fruits.json";

if (file_exists($myfile)) {
    $get_fruits = file_get_contents($myfile);
    print_r(json_decode($get_fruits));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the reading from PHP works fine, when the file is already uploaded to my desired Directory...
But my Question is (now), how to submit the generated *.json-File to my Upload-PHP-Site from my Python-Script

Answer (score 0):

First of all... Sorry for my dumb question....
it all went good after some sleep...

i added the folowing in my QuizGenerator.py:

```
quizName = qName.get()
outfile = open(quizName + '.json', 'w')
outfile.write(jsonData)
outfile.close()

url = 'http://****myURL****/upload.php'
upload = quizName + '.json'
files = {'file': open(upload, 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

my upload.php now looks like this:

```
<?php
    $folder = "json/";
    $path = $folder. basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    print_r($_FILES);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$path);
?>
```

Sleep is good :-)